# How to add dependency in java.library.path in Eclipse?

Tags: java, path

I implement mpi.jar(OPENMPI) in my JAVA application in Eclipse, but when I start to run my app, it reminds me as this picture below(the black font is I use System.getProperty to output library path):

[image]

However, when I check this path with command "java -XshowSettings:properties", it shows that openmpi has already contained:

[image]

Therefore, I want to know what's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Linking to images is strongly discouraged. Please include your code and errors in your question as a properly formatted code block. Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a recurring theme where new users forget to put an `!` in front of their image url, making the image appear a link rather than rendered.